# Security in Base64_encoder Behavior

Tags: php, base64

I am creating a string with `base64_encode` the original output is this one *ZmlsZS1pZC05MjUyMDE5MDIxODIwMTMzOA ==*

More I noticed that if I change the last letter A to B, C, D, F, the `base64_decode` can understand and bring the original text correctly, is this behavior correct? Should not `base64_decode` bring a different result text because it changed the last character?

In the same general question, which one is more certain to use to carry a common text? md5-sha1 base64 encryption etc?

Comment: MD5/SHA1 cannot “carry text”.

Comment: base64 is a way to encode text not encrypt it, for example a base64 string is good for image data, urls, email and  other stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those last characters may be extra padding.

Please see the documentation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

"Padding characters might be added to make the last encoded block contain four Base64 characters."

Comment: Hi Vidal, perfect I had read the documentation more I ended up jumping this line of information, thank you for showing me.

Comment: Glad I helped ! ;)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but base64_encode just converts the encoding of text to a base64 encoding. There is no encryption, hashing, or anything else going on to really obfuscate the original string. It would be like using the ROT13 algorithm and changing the last letter and then un-ROT13 the text. the last character would be different but not appreciably so.

MD5 and SHA1 are hash functions that are one way and the original text will not be recoverable.

Using an encyrption function would allow you to obfuscate the original text and to recover it.